# Not able to break classic lazy initialization Singleton

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I am trying to create various singleton patterns and check for breaks using millions of threads. I was hoping this would lead me to implement Bill Pugh ultimately. But I am not even able to break the classical one.

**Singleton:** Previously tried a million threads, all were having same hashcode. So I made it sleep for 10 sec so that both threads are sure to enter null check condition but all in frustration.

```
package demo2;

public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton soleInstance = null;

    private Singleton() throws InterruptedException {

    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() throws InterruptedException {

        if (soleInstance == null) {

            Thread.sleep(10000);

            soleInstance = new Singleton();

        }

        return soleInstance;

    }

}
```

**Test Class:**

```
package demo2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Test {

    public int makeSingleton() throws InterruptedException {

        Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();

        return s.hashCode();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException  {

        Test t = new Test();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {

                public Integer call() throws InterruptedException {

                     return t.makeSingleton();
                }
            });

            list.add(future.get());
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        List<Integer> list2 = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list2);

    }
}
```

How the hell do I break it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below mentioned code will work.

Change your code. May be you are calling get inside method only and it's waiting to get results & loop count won't increment.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        List<Future<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {

                public Integer call() throws InterruptedException {

                    return Singleton.getInstance().hashCode();
                }
            });

            list.add(future);
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        Set<Integer> output = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
        for(Future<Integer> future : list){
            output.add(future.get());
        }

        System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: no, still returns single hashcode for me. Won't `Thread.sleep` also sleep the current thread by default.

Comment: I tried in my system it is working. Yes both does the same things. I have posted my answer check with both the statements.

Comment: Why do you think you need the `sleep`? Can you shorten your `Thread` creation code? Those `Runnable`s are doing the same thing.

Comment: @cody123 ok your code, also works fine for me, don't call the threads in same class,  but try 'copy/pasting' my Test class code in separate class then it won't work. And I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @garg10may It's ok down voting happens :P I will run your code.

Comment: @garg10may You should not use future.get inside loop. That's the reason you are getting same hashcode. Check yourself and if I solved your problem mark correct.

Comment: @cody123 no that should not be the case, if you will remove the null check condition, the output would give you two hashcodes easily. The scode of future is in loop only. I am not able to access it outside loop.

Comment: @cody123 Your code is not compiling `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method map(Function<? super Integer,? extends R>) in the type Stream<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (new Function<Future<Integer>,Integer>(){})

`

Comment: @garg10may Yes it will compile if you copy the code which you need. Complete code won't compile because it contains two solutions. One was older with the threads and other one is yours modified. I have written in java8.

Comment: @cody123 ok it compiles, I didn't changes types for list. And works fine. So I think now the issue becomes why future.get() in the loop is not working.

Comment: @garg10may because it waits till your thread is not executed and loop count remains same check the documentation. You will know why we always use time as an argument in future. I believe I have answered your question.

Comment: @cody123 thanks, understood that future.get() was the culprit. Maybe edit your answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * If you would like to immediately block waiting
 * for a task, you can use constructions of the form
 * {@code result = exec.submit(aCallable).get();}
 */
<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task);
```

If you use

```
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>()
```

it will block you thread till the result return.

If you want to break the classical singleton pattern, try this code

```
public class BreakSingleton {

    public MySingleton makeSingleton() throws InterruptedException {
        MySingleton s = MySingleton.getInstance();
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BreakSingleton t = new BreakSingleton();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        final List<MySingleton> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Callable<MySingleton>() {
                public MySingleton call() throws InterruptedException {
                    MySingleton mySingleton = t.makeSingleton();
                    list.add(mySingleton);
                    return mySingleton;
                }
            });
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton instance = null;

    private MySingleton() {
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if (instance == null) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            instance = new MySingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```